# Cast Object to Map<?,?> without Unchecked cast warning

Tags: java, object, dictionary, casting

I am working on a project that requires passing around objects, what I am trying to do, is turn that object back into a Map like so.

```
Object o = new Map<String, String>();
Map<String,String> map = (Map<String,String>)o;
```

This seems to work as expected, but I am getting a

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Map

I know that I *could* use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, but I would prefer to do it in a way that I don't have a warning. How would this be done?

Comment: There is no way to avoid the warning if you pass the objects around by casting them down and later up. If you care about the warning you should rethink your design otherwise just suppress it.

Comment: How should I change it then? My protocol allows for an `Object` to be passed around as an extra parameter. In this case, I would like that object to be a map? Is there some option around serialization / deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

You can check, if `o` is a `Map` with `o instanceof Map`. But you can't check the Generic Arguments `<String,String>`, since they're erased at runtime. So even with the `instanceof` check you'll get a warning.

Comment: The generic arguments are actually accessible via reflection.

Comment: @MarcinKról I thought that type erasure means that you can't access this via reflection (as this is not a concretized method or field type)

Comment: @MarcinKról Generic arguments for a class or method are available, but not for a particular object.

Answer (score -1):

Since `Map` extends `Object`, you can just use a `Map` reference instead of downcasting to `Object`.

So in your code, simply replace

```
Object o = new Map<String, String>();
```

with

```
Map<String, String> o = new Map<>();
```

And then your second line (with the unchecked cast) becomes unnecessary.

Comment: A non-generic map when casted to a generic map will give warning.

Comment: @KumarAbhinav Who is casting a non-generic map to a generic map? It's a generic map, just using Java 7 diamond notation...

Comment: OP wants to create a Map from Object and not create a map reference directly and he wants to do this without warnings.So although you are technically correct,its not the right answer

Comment: @KumarAbhinav if OP is provided with an `Object` and does not have control over its being downcast, then hinneLinks answer is correct (it is not possible). The question should be clarified.

Comment: OP's question has a design flaw from the beginning and its not even possible.